# IOS: How do I populate a UITableView which is within a nib?

Tags: ios

I have a nib file in which there is a `UILabel` and a `UITableView`.

So I've created 2 outlets - one for the label the other one for the `UITableView`.

Then I've created a subclass of `TableViewController` which knows how to populate a `UITableView` the way I want to. With it I'm going to populate that my `UITableView`.

Then in `viewDidLoad` of the controller for that nib file I do

```
[myTableViewController setView: myTableViewOutlet]
```

I expect the functions `numberOfRowsInsection` and other such from `myTableViewController` will be called after that so my `UITableView` gest populated.

But this does not happen and my `UITableView` remains empty..

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things I can think of that might be missing:

1. Set data source and delegate of the tableview to the controller;
2. Call reload data method on the tableview to trigger a reload.